# Mysql search between date

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM stockmanagement2.invoice_item
WHERE (cast(invoice_date as date) BETWEEN '01/07/2019' AND 
'31/07/2019' )
```

I GOT THIS ANSWER AFTER USED THIS COMMAND BUT I HAVE SOME RECORDS AS PER DATE
3   34  23:51:38

```
SELECT * FROM stockmanagement2.invoice_item 
 WHERE (cast(invoice_date as date) BETWEEN '01/07/2019' AND 
 '31/07/2019' )
 LIMIT 0, 1000

0 row(s) returned   0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Comment: Please stop shouting

Comment: If you every enter dates into a query as strings, you should use `YYYY-MM-DD` format thats the format MySQL likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  your invoice_date is a string  in format  '%d/%m/%Y' instead of cast you should use str_to_date

```
SELECT * 
FROM stockmanagement2.invoice_item
WHERE str_to_date(invoice_date, '%d/%m/%Y')  
    BETWEEN  str_to_date('01/07/2019' ,  '%d/%m/%Y') 
        AND  str_to_date('31/07/2019' ,  '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit of overkill, converting the text input dates? Wouldn't it be simpler to tell the OP to use the right format for a MySQL date string parameter i.e. `'2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'`

Comment: but it's working, some client needs to date format dd/mm/yyyy, so i can't use '2019-07-01'